# Deep Clone of List<T> with out, where T is IClonable

Tags: c#, collections, clone

I have the below class for generating Hierarchy Tree structure

```
public class DynaTreeNode
{
    #region---Property---
    public string title { get; set; }     
    public string key { get; set; }
    public object icon { get; set; }
    List<DynaTreeNode> _children = new List<DynaTreeNode>();
    public List<DynaTreeNode> children
    {
        get { return _children; }
        set { _children = value; }
    }      
}
```

Also i have a list of DynaTreeNode

```
List<DynaTreeNode> wholeTree = new List<DynaTreeNode>();//originally from DB
```

Now i want to clone this List collection into a new List

Todo this I am thinking to use

```
wholeTree.Select(i => i.Clone()).ToList();
```

In this case i need to implement IClonable Interface to DynaTreeNode. But the problem is IClonable will not do a deep copy. From http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2003/04/09/49935.aspx

Referred [How do I clone a generic list in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222598/how-do-i-clone-a-generic-list-in-c)

This answer also use IClonable.

***How can I clone my List with deep copy?***.

**Note:** I want all the children (List) also should get cloned.

Answer (score 3):

If performance is not too much of an issue, you can use serialization to implement an general deep cloning approach (e.g., see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251277/net-deep-cloning-what-is-the-best-way-to-do-that/1822146#1822146), [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4152733/how-to-implement-clone-and-copy-method-inside-a-class/4152767#4152767), [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8935056/cloning-objects-without-serialization), or have a look at this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23832/Implementing-Deep-Cloning-via-Serializing-objects)).

If this is not an option (e.g., due to performance concerns), you'll have to implement a dedicated method to clone your nodes. For instance, your approach

```
wholeTree.Select(i => i.Clone()).ToList();
```

is perfectly [valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222598/how-do-i-clone-a-generic-list-in-c/222640#222640). Your own implementation of the Clone method may of course return a deep clone (ICloneable does not specify whether deep or shallow; this is the reason why many people consider ICloneable harmful)

Comment: I already mentioned that i read this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/222598/how-do-i-clone-a-generic-list-in-c . This itself have the answer with a static method DeepClone and use Serialization. But would like to know is there any other way other than serialization :)

Answer (score 1):

My answer is simple (sorry, i have bad english for hard-answer :))

You may use recursion for select subelements.

You need write function which will be call self and return subelements

Comment: Here's an answer for Cloning Method using Recursion and Reflection: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52097307/4707576